# In Python trying to find changes in each row individually comparing with previous dictionary

Tags: dictionary, row, md5, sha, hashlib

```
enter code here
```

sample data

```
1,sam,kawara,MI,208 sample st,MI,USA,Sales,East,Novi

2,simi,kawara,OH,10 Tech Road,MI,USA,Sales,East,Euclid

3,John,Doe,CA,20 Ex G Road,CA,USA,Sales,West,Los Angles

4,Jack,Max,NY,15 Temp St,OH,USA,Sales,East,Newyork
```

Implemented hashlib and using md5: on each line, the output stored as dictionary

*datafile before

```
 {'1': '8128f724f8648a3781bcce6607e4afd9',
 '2': '2fb69d6e9cfbec276b78b04a4e026f4c',
 '3': '4bc36e08b8325f21422b1ab302cc54a7',
 '4': '3e116f2999be684f18a666b65d2d5835'}*
```

Implemented hashlib and using sha1: on each line

datafile1

```
{'1': '9dd9cc6254c6ac7799189b2ba33ed78a6042cc6a', 
'2': 'f29000788b6ffc4771bdbddf2777e909c9c6ce7e', 
'3': 'b47ab17c74c0c04230e2954aa183b0d62deba0a5', 
'4': 'ba881dcb79b41d3a810ea15bd3000171ba7768a0'}
```

=**After changing the last field data in the row**====================================

```
enter code here
```

only changed data in line 1, last field from "Novi" to "Detroit"

```
1,sam,kawara,MI,208 sample st,MI,USA,Sales,East,Detroit

2,simi,kawara,OH,10 Tech Road,MI,USA,Sales,East,Euclid

3,John,Doe,CA,20 Ex G Road,CA,USA,Sales,West,Los Angles

4,Jack,Max,NY,15 Temp St,OH,USA,Sales,East,Newyork
```

*Implemented hashlib and using md5: on each line

datafile  after change

```
{'1': '21b29e74267886d15064d7745f226368', 
'2': '8f97e8730798cb59ac55988fcafcda77', 
'3': '86b669c234f2c9bfa1ac5cf64b7c58a2',
 '4': 'c3b80e153b557a538a607144e13c8cd5'}*
```

Implemented hashlib and using sha1: on each line

datafile1

```
 {'1': '08030a28c665d26cb905691d90b1d9a10d6f2564', 
'2': '3468b3a73a366ec31474c5d91545962d3c54cbb7', 
'3': 'af8be87ce346f7f40c26f9660132de2dceb8792a', 
'4': 'a964b79b79d5d38928d9bf792d663ff51be092b2'}
```

I changed data in first row only. My requirement to individually find changes in each row by comparing the current dictionary output of each row based on id(1,2,3....) to the previous dictionary stored in file.

What could I do? Only the first row last field data is changed, i am updating the row to (md5,sha) line by line. I am expecting only the first row md5 out to be changed, but why is the output changed for the remaining row too.

[my code [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh4I2.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solved thanks...

Comment: Implement it at row level , or column level based on the requirement. Based on the requirement encoding needs to be done ,at row level or column level and update to it to md5 and get the hex_digest().